# How to save/copy file in php script between two windows servers with authorization?

Tags: php, windows, authorization, unc

I want to copy/save file in php script from one Windows Server (source) to second Windows Server (dist). I cant use anonymous "Guest" account, I need to authorize on dist server by user and pass.

Have you any idea how to do this?

I tried to to this with UNC paths like this: "\path\to\dist\file.txt" but I cant force user authorization and cant change default Guest user.

Comment: So you want to access a Windows share. Do any of the servers belong to an Active Directory domain? When you say you can't do you mean you don't know or you're not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the exec function in php to copy the filese over the Windows Commandline.

Try with: [link text](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php)

Comment: @nusbit: sorry, but allowing PHP to execute command like "exec, system, passthrue" is not save for web applications.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by custom *.bat file which mount appriopriate drive and directory